# Can't access the BIOS in a Lenovo ThinkPad T430i

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, virtualization

I have a ThinkPad T430i running Windows 10. I want to enable virtualization, so I need to access the BIOS to enable the feature.

When I reboot my laptop it asks me to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to interrupt the booting and once I do it asks me to press <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the BIOS setup. However, when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> it just shows me a blank screen.

I tried updating my BIOS to the latest version (from https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/nz/en/downloads/ds029252) but it still does the same thing.

How do I get access to the BIOS or how do I enable virtualization without going into the BIOS?

Comment: Try unplug the battery and plug it in, then reboot to enter Bios.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have one issue that my battery totally bad that if I don't put plug than my Laptop will not start. So please suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the ThinkPad and try:

1. Press ThinkVantage button -> Press F1 -> Enter BIOS

or

2. Press F12 to run boot menu -> Press Tab to switch tab -> Select enter BIOS -> Hit Enter.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But all goes to BIOS but always blank Screen. 

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade the BIOS version?

Comment: How to do that, Kindly can you guide.

Comment: Here is a guide on how to install the BIOS http://x220.mcdonnelltech.com/bios/ Follow it to downgrade the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

remove the hard drive, then when the unit boots up you'll get the boot menu, which will then allow you to tab to the App menu and enter into the Bios setup.

I updated my bios and then couldn't get the F keys or enter key to work to get into the bios. Once I did above, I found under Config -> Keyboard/Mouse the F1-F12 as Primary Function was disabled. I enabled that which then allowed me to press F1 again to get into the bios.